# Lift framework: Not able to render table rows using comet properly

Tags: lift

In my web page I have a text box in which user enters an item name that would be sent to server asynchronously, that message would be sent to CometActor then further it adds additional information to it and in the render method it tries to append a new row to existing table on the page asynchronously. Whenever I add an item always new row is getting placed on top of table rather than as table row, after that if I press refresh it is getting placed properly in the table. Here is

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" class="display" id="example">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Time</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="lift:comet?type=ProvisionComet">
      <tr id="tr_content">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

LiftActor object

```
object ItemsServer extends LiftActor with ListenerManager {
  private var items = Vector[Item]()
  private lazy val date: Box[Date] = DependencyFactory.inject[Date] // inject the date

  def createUpdate = items

  override def lowPriority = {
    case s: String => items :+= new Item(items.length + 1, s, date.map(_.toString));         updateListeners()
    case _ => None
 }
}
```

Comet Actor

```
class ItemComet extends CometActor with CometListener {
  private var items = Vector[Item]()

  def registerWith = ItemsServer

  override def lowPriority = {
    case v: Vector[Item] => items = v; reRender()
  }

  def render = "#tr_content *" #> {
    items.map(i => {
      <td>{i.sNum}</td>
      <td>{i.itemName}</td>
      <td>{i.updatedTime.toString}</td>
  })
}
```

The result before refresh is 
[image: Before refresh result]

The result after refresh
[image: After refresh result]

How to get the correct result without refreshing?

render method is the place where I am adding rows

Comment: Can you post the code showing how you add the row when the Actor receives a message?

Comment: render method place where I am adding new rows.

Comment: I had the same issue while using Chrome and IE. My app was working fine in Firefox. Even in Chrome it started working few mins after server start. Also i had this issue only in localhost, whereas the hosted app worked fine in IE, Chrome FF. So try in different browsers and in hosted environments.

Comment: No it is the same even in FF and other browsers. When I checked generated HTML, there is div tag getting added magically on top of table tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the `class` attribute from `tbody` to `table`:

```
<table class="lift:comet?type=ProvisionComet" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" class="display" id="example">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Time</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody >
  <tr id="tr_content">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Well never mind... that solves the problem of the rows appearing above the header, but it prints a header for every row!